# Array falls within limits set however I keep on getting a False statement

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array and I checked that the minimum and maximum are within the limits.

The limits are 840 as minimum and 940 as maximum, and the actual min and max of my array was 846.3 and 910.8. So the array is within limits.

I wrote some code to check that, and the way I want it to work is to check if the array `y_array[:,[0]]`is within limits and if it is, it would display: `True`. However I keep getting `False` why is that? I also would like to index the values which would not be in range, should they not be as I have multiple arrays with their own limits to check, however I haven't managed that yet

```
# Initialization of range
i, j = 840, 940
 
# Test if List contains elements in Range
res_teflon = all(value > i and value < j for value in y_array[:,[0]])
 
# printing result
print("List contains all values in range : " + str(res_teflon))
```

**ADDENDUM**

[Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Bc6SwZ3NEGI_WWoEfv_VpUNrKANS-q6e?usp=share_link) to array.
Array can accessed by doing the following:

```
A = numpy.load('y_array.npy')
```

Comment: Why does `940` show up instead of `j` in your test?

Comment: It supposed to be `j` yes not 940 just fixed it now. What I said still applies.

Comment: What does a comma in python slice notation do?

Comment: @JonSG my `y_array` consists of 3 columns and I wanted to select column `0`

Comment: You'll want to check what `y_array[:,[0]]` is, as Python isn't lying here. Maybe you're grabbing the wrong slice.

Comment: did you want `res_teflon = all(value[0] > i and value[0] < j for value in y_array)`?

Comment: Just check it explicitly. Run `import numpy` and then: indices = `np.where((y_array[:,[0]] < i) | (y_array[:,[0]] > j))`. That's all the indices that do not meet the condition.

Comment: @RandomDavis Just checked with your line of code and got the [following] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv4ey.png) not sure what it means though

Comment: @JonSG Yes essentially that does the same procedure and in fact I get the same result

Comment: In addendum I included a link for the array containing the `0` column only.